# Is it possible to capture the screen (video) with Movie Studio Platinum 13?

Tags: vegas-pro, video-capture

Is it possible to capture the screen (video) with Movie Studio Platinum 13 ?

if yes , where do I do that ?

Comment: No, it's not possible.
Look here: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/software-to-capture-high-quality-screen-casts